# Running against intensive queries the mirror database

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-mirroring

For SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, we have a mirrored database named X1. We can query the secondary DB. I would like to extract data from this secondary mirrored database (X1) with SELECT queries and insert the into results into another, non-mirrored, database named "Y1" that is on the same instance as the secondary mirrored database then do extensive SQL operations on "Y1".

My question is, will these extensive SQL queries on "Y1" affect the smooth running of the primary X1 database? Given the primary is on a different machine and uses different disks?

Comment: Are all of these databases on the same host? The same SQL Server instance? Because they all share the same memory and that is usually the bottleneck

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Database X1 is the mirrored one, there is no sharing on its primary instance, Database Y1 is on the same instance as the secondary X1. It's database Y1 that will have the high workload (Y1 is not mirrored).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, will these extensive SQL queries on "Y1" affect the smooth running of the primary X1 database?

There will be no impact ,you also may not see any issue with locking,blockings unless you do many DDL operations on primary..

Comment: If the primary were to fail over to the mirrored version, would the secondary server be up to date with the primary, would it be able to catch up?